# Linq-to-Sql Contains an int? inside a list of int

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, type-safety, linq-to-sql

Curious if there is a better way to write a repository method that receives argument `List<int>` and checks if the database `Contains` an `int?`.

```
public List<int> GetNumbersByNumbers(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    var convertedNumbers = numbers.Select(m => (int?)m);
    return Context.TblNumbers
        .Where(m => convertedNumbers.Contains(m.Number))
        .Select(m => m.Number.GetValueOrDefault())
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to do this is to remove `NULL` values from the comparison to begin with, like so:

```
return Context.TblNumbers
              .Where(m => m.Number != null)
              .Where(m => convertedNumbers.Contains(m.Number.Value))
              .Select(m => m.Number.Value)
              .ToList();
```

I think this also reads more naturally since you only have the chance to match on non-null values anyway, instead of `GetValueOrDefault()` which implies you might need to get a default value.

Comment: Since you use the actual value `m.Number.Value` there's no need to convert the `numbers` to `convertedNumbers` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the method to behave the exact same way, then no. Since your table accepts nulls, even though your method signature only deals with non-nullable value types, you still have to map to a collection of nullable ints when using `Contains`.

By the way, it may be more efficient to call `.ToList()` and then select using `GetValueOrDefault()` depending on how the provider translates `GetValueOrDefault()` to SQL.